# Using GROUP BY with SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a `SQLDataSource` in an ASP.NET Web Form, bound to a `GridView` and would like to perform a `GROUP BY` on the underlying data after it has been bound.

I would like the grouped data to appear in a separate `GridView`.

How would I accomplish this task?

Comment: what have u tried so far, display it

Answer (score 0):

> would like to perform a GROUP BY on the underlying data **after it has
>   been bound**.

You cannot do that. Once the data is bound, it is bound. The same data will be displayed in the gridview however it was pulled in query with out without grouping. You cannot change it afterwards.

I am thinking you want something different as your question suggests. You want to be able to group on the fly depending on what field the user select. For that you will need different set of controls. May be a dropdownlist and a Gridview Combination? That will be a different scenario.

You can also bound sql datasource on the fly in C# code rather than in ASP.NET code. In that you would be able to achieve it with some additional controls like if this button is clicked, group by this field or if that button is clicked, group by that field.